# How to require the `this` type to be present in the generic of a method parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a class in TypeScript that allows me to connect different types of elements in a sort of network. The allowed target type for each type of element should be constrainable, so I wrote this really simple generic class:

```
abstract class Element<Target = unknown> {
  targets: Target[] = [];

  into(...targets: Target[]): this {
    // implementation omitted for brevity
    return this;
  }
}
```

This gives me correct type checking for things like this:

```
class First extends Element<First | Second> { // Can connect to First or Second
  firstProp = "";
}
class Second extends Element<First | Second> { // Can connect to First or Second
  secondProp = "";
}
class Third extends Element<Third> { // Can only connect to itself
  thirdProp = "";
}

const first = new First();
const second = new Second();
const third = new Third();

first.into(first); // works, OK
first.into(second); // works, OK
first.into(third); // error, OK
```

So far, so good. Then, I wanted to add a convenience method to the class that allows me to specify connections the other way around by specifying a set of sources to connect from. However, I can't seem to come up with the correct signature to get this done, so I tried to add this method:

```
from(...sources: Element<this>): this {
  // omitted again
  return this;
}

// This should work now:
first.from(second); // But errors
```

But it doesn't work because the signature as it is requires the `sources` to be of type `Element<First>`, whereas `second` is of type `Element<First | Second>`, so TypeScript errors correctly because `First` does not extend `First | Second`, but the other way around. This is a problem, as it's possible to write a generic like `X extends this` but, of course, not a generic like `this extends X`.

So the type of `sources` should be an array of `Element`s that have the `this` of `from`'s instance in their `Target` union, but I have no idea how to pull something like this off in TypeScript or if it is even possible.

I have tried many variations to the signature, trying combinations with conditional types and other good stuff. Still, nothing has worked so far, and I slowly start to believe I have tried so many wrong things that I'm completely on the wrong track by now and that I'm missing something completely obvious here, so any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sooooo... [this](https://tsplay.dev/WY3RdN)? I'm unsure what you're asking but if you play around with it more and believe that it solves your problem, I'll be happy to explain in a detailed answer.

Comment: @caTS Perfect! That does the trick nicely! I'll gladly accept this as the answer to the question. I think I can follow most of what you're doing there, so an explanation of what's going on exactly would definitely be great :) Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  from<Sources extends Element<unknown>[]>(...sources: {
    [K in keyof Sources]: this extends Sources[K]["targets"][number] ? Sources[K] : Error & { error: ["This class's targets do not include", Target] };
  }): this {
    // omitted again
    return this;
  }
```

Using a generic to infer the types of the targets, we can then, inside the type of the rest parameters, check each of the given elements' target. If it doesn't match with `this`, then we "change" the expected type to `Error & { ... }`, essentially giving the user a helpful error message.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=4&pln=9&pc=3#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgogDwA4FN4xNl8BbfAOwgB4AVYKAc30QF4EBXSga0oHsA7pQB8CAN4BYAFAIEERiwhgAXAgbNWAbQC6CDroDcMmXICW1fgAoAdHYWblajUt0BKNRAAWZjFNlyCAD0QQhmZLikFNTAEGb8lAj8ZGYQEPgAJggAZvxQCCBQ+ABuqQCepoFFEJxQid6+xgEAviYB2VDJNADK-LWw+Bj42OmUGRg4BEQk5FS03HxCoroitnZgfVADqhKVcloA0mGJPPhl-NkIvf2DOp4+QyNU41eb24c6WgBEDkpgX59KJwyCB8FA9AB+V43MAfBBqTBQTr5ABkEgQYORam+dAeSFQ6AA5BhfqwMBl+AgBIgLChOBl8F8ADTqRSsPTNJpyZoeeR4-yBYKhZKpdJZYBMYAWPYIaq1eoPLkIVrSFUyFBoDAAMTMUEgGKeYwmeEIyhm0VoOr1iAAPldCAkMmJxEKEABhYCJWAJSim+SUq36vL271jSrZXWQAAKnVw+gQXy+TRVGvQIcdBtGL0mpuIUTmNEDtvTY2dro9Xp9fogAcjiGD3QdYYCYCbGRj-DjHETyfVBIwuN1WWGWeNUzN+eo9B8UCd6JC7s9SUoyDKSCr8H9YWU+GQ2UqDVnHa7CaTMjV0lD+oj1vjvsECCLVjcTSviFboayHHvJYyz9fCT6oeX5UvgD6DrO-5tDekA2BYNZWDBEAvq6gh5DwYAsgA8gcMhIXBlhWB+jooQuaFQBh2G4dI+HwdYwGkaEmJ5FR0F1jYHTJERbYvnh7GcWQiF1rxNH8Z0gnEWMLJISJ+ECVYDGGK6zFQEAA)